# Nested while loop gets executed, outer loop not

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am pretty new to Java and currently, I am working on a Vigenere cipher de/encryption.
I already got the de- and encryption with a known key down, the only thing I want to do now is a dictionary attack. For this, the algorithm takes a line from a text file and uses it as a key to decipher the message, then it takes that deciphered message and cross-references it with the dictionary again (and if the key produced a legit word, it will decrypt the rest of the message with that key).

```
public static String decoderNoKey(String msg, Scanner words) {
Scanner words2 = words;
while (words.hasNextLine()) {
  String dicStr = words.nextLine();
  String result = decoder(msg, dicStr);

  while (words2.hasNextLine()) {
    String meta = words2.nextLine();
    if(result.equalsIgnoreCase(meta)) {
      System.out.println("Found a matching message: " + result);
      System.out.println("This is the corresponding key: " + dicStr);
      return meta;
    }
  }
 }
  return "There was no matching word";
}
```

this is my code, the decoder(); Method works just fine. If I try to enter a legit cipher, the problem is, the outer while loop only executes one time (found that out over print statements).
The words-file is quite big as well, 84000+ words.

Comment: When your inner loop is done, so is your outer loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`words2` is not a copy of `words`. It's a new name referring to the same object... So your inner loop is exhausting your scanner, and your outer loop no longer has anything to do.